# How to use the tidyr::spread value parameter with its value stored as a string variable?

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm running several `tidyr::spread` inside a cycle, where value of the `value` parameter changes. However, `value` requies "the bare (unquoted) name"...

```
mydata <- structure(list(ID = c(26242055, 26242254, 26243093, 26248278, 
26252563, 26255141, 26242055), Target = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), opendt = c("2013-01-31", "2013-01-31", "2013-01-31", "2013-01-31", 
"2013-01-31", "2013-01-31", "2013-01-31"), txn_bc_am_cnt = c(1, 
2, 1, 27, 1, 2, 1), txn_bc_am_sum = c(200000, 19040.02, 35000, 
143227.5, 11910, 32212.8, 200000), delta = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3)), .Names = c("ID", "Target", "opendt", "txn_bc_am_cnt", "txn_bc_am_sum", 
"delta"), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")

x <- c("txn_bc_am_sum", "txn_bc_am_cnt")
```

So this works:

```
tidyr::spread(mydata[,c("ID", "Target", "opendt", x[1], "delta")], 
key = delta, value = txn_bc_am_sum)
```

But this fails:

```
tidyr::spread(mydata[,c("ID", "Target", "opendt", x[1], "delta")], 
key = delta, value = x[1])
```

How can I make it work with changing `value`? I'm sure there is an elegant workaround, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tidyr functions do not seem to support the new rlang syntax, so the best bet right now is to use the `?spread_` standard evaluation version of the function

```
tidyr::spread_(mydata[,c("ID", "Target", "opendt", x[1], "delta")], 
    key_col = "delta", value_col = x[1])
```

Comment: … or use the development version of tidyr, which does support quasiquotations.

Comment: @KonradRudolph True. Though do you know in later versions of the tidyverse if `syms` is exported? Always seems odd to have to use `rlang::sym` to convert a string into a symbol that can be used with `!!`.

Comment: I have no idea — but using `!!` works with character strings and `quote`’d expressions anyway, so `rlang::sym` isn’t needed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think that's true. See `x<-"cyl"; mtcars %>% group_by(!!x) %>% summarize(mean(mpg))` for example compared to `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(mean(mpg))`

Comment: Ah. It works for `spread`. Anyway, I strongly oppose stringly-typed variables anyway; the `quote` variant works.